# ViewFlipper With One Child (LinearLayout)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewflipper

I' have a ViewFlipper, which contains one child only (a linearlayout), the problem I have is when I switch view's, it goes well and displays the next view and so on. But the animation doesn't goes smoothly, by that I mean that the current screen moves while next one shows up!
In this case, the current screen gets removed and the next one slides in.

How can I make the current screen to slide away, and let the next one slide in while have one child in the ViewFlipper? I've been looking all over, can't find anything!

xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout">
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/dateView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
        />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/myListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />  
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

android code:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
            currentX = event.getX();
            if (Math.abs(currentX - downXValue) >= v.getWidth()/5){
                if(currentX < downXValue){
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                    dateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    todoAdapter.clear();
                    todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    vf.setInAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_in);
                    vf.setOutAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_out);
                    vf.showPrevious();
                }
                else{
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                    dateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    todoAdapter.clear();
                    todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    vf.setInAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.push_right_in);
                    vf.setOutAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.push_right_out);   
                    vf.showNext();
                }   
            }
            break;
        }
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewSwitcher` instead. Implement a `ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory` to provide the inside view (you can use a `LayoutInflater` with a layout xml), set it using `ViewSwitcher.setFactory` and use `ViewSwitcher.getNextView` and `View.findViewById` to find and set your components accordingly.

A `ViewSwitcher` is also a subclass of `ViewAnimator` so you can set the in/out animations and use `showNext` and `showPrevious` as you are already familiar with.

Comment: But I will need to add the views? And my view in this case is just one LinearLayout, with a ListView inside.

Comment: Place the layout in a separate xml file and use a `LayoutInflater` to provide the view in the `ViewFactory`.

Comment: Already tried that, and it doesn't work. Sure, it will indeed show the next view. But that current move wont slide away as the new one slides in, the current one just get delete at once.

Comment: No, a `ViewSwitcher` consists of two views for that very reason. You keep manipulating `getNextView` and show it.